# Can not update the arrays from the put endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, joi

This is one simple api using express where the results are stored in a course array. The validation logics are stored into the validateCourse function.

Now the problem is the `POST` endpoint is working correctly but while I'm trying to update through the `PUT` endpoint i'm getting **404** error:

`name is required`.

Can anyone tell me where is the problem in the logic or the PUT endpoint thus the update option is not working.

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const courses = [
    { id: 1, name: 'course1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'course2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'course3' }
]
app.post('/api/courses', (req, res) => {

    const result = validateCourse(req.body);

    // console.log(result);

    if (result.error) {
        res.status(400).send(result.error.details[0].message);
        return;
    }

    const course = {
        id: courses.length + 1,
        name: req.body.name
    };
    courses.push(course);
    res.send(course);
});

app.put('/api/courses/:id', (req, res) => {

    //Search course by get method
    //If not found return error 404

    const course = courses.find(c => c.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
    if (!course) res.status(404).send('not found with the given id');

    //validate
    //if invalid ,return 400 bad request

    const result = validateCourse(req.body);
    // const {error} = validateCourse(req.body);

    if (result) {
        res.status(400).send(result.error.details[0].message);
        console.log(result.error.details);
        return;
    }


    //if valid then update course
    //Return the updated course to client
    course.name = req.body.name;
    res.send(course);
});


//INPUT VALIDATION//

function validateCourse(course) {
    const schema = {
        name: Joi.string().min(3).required()
    };
    return Joi.validate(course, schema);
}
```

Comment: Hi have you checked if `req.body.name` is defined?

Comment: It's present in the course object as name:req.body.name. Do i have to define it through a new variable? @t3__rry

Comment: I meant are you actually getting a value from the `req` object?

Comment: Just add `console.log(req.body)` above `const result = validateCourse(req.body);` to see what data is comming in. Is the name there?

Comment: I'm getting this through console.log while making requests from 
POST endpoint : { name: 'java course' }
But this is i'm getting from PUT endpoint through console.log
{}
[ { message: '"name" is required',
    path: [ 'name' ],
    type: 'any.required',
    context: { key: 'name', label: 'name' } } ]     @Molda

Comment: @t3__rry Through PUT endpoint getting an empty object.                                 
{}
[ { message: '"name" is required',
    path: [ 'name' ],
    type: 'any.required',
    context: { key: 'name', label: 'name' } } ]

Comment: So the req.body is `{}` if i understand, right? So there's no data coming in. How do you make the request to your app? From browser, Postman or something else??

Comment: Ok so you are not passing the data in the `body` of the request

Comment: I'm making the request from Postman.
And passing the data in JSON FORMAT 
 {
 "name": "javascript course"
}
and this is the route 
http://localhost:4000/api/courses/1
@Molda

Comment: I did pass the data in JSON format through this route
 {
 "name": "javascript course"
}

http://localhost:4000/api/courses/1  @t3__rry